# Where does the following question about inflating bicycle tyres belong?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

> I want to inflate both of my bicycle's tyres. Both valves have a
>   cover. I remove the cover of the first valve and inflate the tire. 
>   Now, what is the better way to proceed:
>
> 1. Put the cover back on the first tire and remove the cover of the
>      second tire  or
> 2. Remove the cover of the second tire and put it on
>      the first tire?
>
> After that, I'd continue with inflating the second tire and after that
>   putting the spare cover on it.

I guess this is intended as kind of a thinking-out-of-the-box-question.

Comment: [bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This seems like an overly trivial question asking for an undefined _best way_. It might not fit anywhere in the network.

Comment: @ErikA fair enough.

Comment: You don't define what "better" means to you. What about this situation are you interested in? The physics of inflated tires? The economy of motion? What makes "better" better? I may be wrong but I'm not even sure that the covers are necessary for air retention, only for keeping dirt out.

Comment: I don't know if one should do this on StackExchange, but I left the definition of "better" open on purpose. I wanted answers thinking outside-the-box.

Comment: @MichaelBauer, that's a good way to get your question closed as "primarily opinion-based".

Answer (score 4):

We have a [dedicated site](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/) for bicycle questions.

> #### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Bicycles Stack Exchange is for people who build and repair bicycles, people who train cycling, or commute on bicycles.
>
> Most questions regarding bicycles, tricycles, unicycles, handcycles, and their use are on topic for this site.

(from their [Help Center](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))

Comment: (but to be honest, I doubt there's much difference between the two options you mention. I could be wrong though...)

Comment: The "I could be wrong though" part is what I'm trying to be enlighted about ;)
 And I don't know wether the answers are bike-specific...